# Display specific content for visitors coming from specific sites

Tags: javascript, html

For the same website (html), I need to display specific content based on where did they come from (referrer).

Example:

Inside 0.html we have something like:

```
<html>
<content for visitors from example1.com>
<content for visitors from example2.com>
</html>
```

So:

Visitor1 clicks on link from example1.com pointed to otherexample.com/0.html --> Display only

```
<content for visitors coming from example1.com>
```

Visitor2 clicks on link from example3.com pointed to otherexample.com/0.html --> Display only

```
<content for visitors coming from example2.com>
```

1. Is this possible with javascript/html?
2. What about displaying an external .html inside the 0.html using this rules?

Comment: sounds like what you need is `document.referrer`

Comment: It _is_ possible with javascript — your script can look at `document.referrer`. There are various ways to pull content into the current page, or do a redirect to a different page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this yourself? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten thank you for your suggestion, I understand that there are many lazy people around here and that's your point. I am a DIY person and I've been trying a lot of methods I've found on stackoverflow and this is why I had no other choice than asking for experts advise for the best options I have for my need. Stackoverflow it's a little over-flowed with information and for people like me it's difficult to understand which is the best choice for a specific need, project or language. I will keep in mind the good-question suggestions as well. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Sphinx and Stephen P actually I found the solution thanks to your constructive and productive responses.

Comment: Its not just because of lazy people... questions that ask open questions that are likely to be answered with opinions are off topic because answers should be fact-based (and also, I suspect, to prevent arguments over who's opinion is best :) ) My suggestion is to make an attempt at coding it and show us what you have done and what problems you run into. You might be able to get some advice on the best way to do things once you have an actual starting point for discussion.

Comment: I totally agree and understand the reasons @FluffyKitten , I will put a major effort on my next question. Thank you for keeping this community great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
    <script>
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?subdomain\.example\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
   document.write('<img src="https://example.com/img/logo.png" width="60%">');
}
    </script>
```

This will load an image only for visitors who come from a specific subdomain.